# Using .keyup function to filter auto complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, keyup

Am using .keyup to filter my auto complete.

However it only allows me to enter the first digit. so if my data is "Apple"

when i type A -  it shows Apple but i cannot type "AP" as the "P" disappears.

I was expecting that i can write the whole word rather than the first letter.

Code:

```
<input id="ac" /> <span></span>

var validOptions = "@Url.Action("SerialProdNumStockSiteAutoComplete", "Ajax")?stocksitenum=LW&model=" + $("#Form_Prod_Num").val();
previousValue = "";

     $('#ac').autocomplete({
            autoFocus: true,
            source: validOptions
        }).keyup(function () {
            var isValid = false;
            for (i in validOptions) {
                if (validOptions[i].toLowerCase().match(this.value.toLowerCase())) {
                    isValid = true;
                }
            }
            if (!isValid) {
                this.value = previousValue
            } else {
                previousValue = this.value;
            }
        });
```

This was working when i used dummy data, but when i changed this to url.action it only worked for the first letter rather than the whole word.

I do have a fiddle that [works](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/j3AN7)  - **however when i added my "URL.action" it only accepted the first letter. (There are about 5000 values)**

Comment: could you maybe provide a fiddle or some?

Comment: I do have a fiddle that works http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/j3AN7/   - however when i added my "URL.action" it only accepted the first letter...

Comment: Try using single quotes within your validOptions variable since you enclosed it with double quotes: `var validOptions = "@Url.Action('SerialProdNumStockSiteAutoComplete', 'Ajax')?stocksitenum=LW&model=" + $("#Form_Prod_Num").val();`

Comment: it gives me error - "Bad compile constant value"

Comment: URL provided gives me error: `GET http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/@Url.Action('SerialProdNumStockSiteAutoComplete',%20'Ajax')?stocksitenum=LW&model=undefined&term=a 404 (NOT FOUND)`

Comment: @NightOwlPrgmr that won't work.  Url.Action is processed server-side and ' is for a character, not a string.

Comment: @freedomn-m so what can i do to make it string

Comment: @freedomn-m for example it will return something like this "B061030029,LL-XXX," so for this example i can only type B - i cannot type "B0"

Comment: @mali Provide the rendered html (right click in browser, view page source) after the Url.Action (preferably with a very small subset of data (3-4 records))

Comment: it doesnt show it in page source the url.action nor in the inspect element

Answer (score 0):

In the fiddle, you're setting your available options as an array:

```
var validOptions = ["Bold", "Normal", "Default", "100", "200"]
```

if you take the result of your action (as called directly) and replace this into the jsfiddle, you'll get (taking from comment):

```
var validOptions = "B061030029,LL-XXX,"
```

or, depending on whether the quotes in the comment are included (unlikely):

```
var validOptions = ""B061030029,LL-XXX,""
```

either way, these aren't the same.

Use view-source in the browser to see what is being rendered by the Url.Action.

You can change your action to return the string:

```
"[\"B061030029\", \"LL-XXX\" ]";
```

which would then give:

```
var validOptions = ["B061030029", "LL-XXX"]
```

which matches the original options.

For neatness, you could do this with a PartialView and still continue to return the values from the action as a string list and format in the partial view rather than the controller.

Comment: there is about 5 thousand values. not just 1.

Comment: Then your jsfiddle won't work - I provided a method to convert the Url.Action to match the jsfiddle as requested.  There was no mention in the question about there being too many values.

Comment: oh sorry, so why is it that it only shows the first letter?

Comment: No problem, this should still work, but the whole paradigm would be completely sucky!  Stop using autocomplete with pre-provided values and use the remote data option: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

Comment: thats complicated, the way iv done it is simple, its working with hard coded data but not with url.action, and i still dont understand why it only accepts the first letter and not the whole word..

Comment: right, it works with hard coded data but for some reason its not working with the url.action